# Add Progress Bar Spinner to Dialog Pop Up WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

I have tried to implement a Progress Bar Spinner for the below code.  I am fairly new to android programming and have tried searching and trying examples.  The code below is what I have that is working for the pop up to display and have a webview with a custom close button.  Could someone please show me or instruct me on how to use the progress spinner with the following code?  Thank you.

```
package com.example.expopup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Dialog myDialog;
Button myButton;


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClkBtn);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {

            myDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
            myDialog.setTitle("Test");
            myDialog.setCancelable(true);

            WebView myWebView = (WebView)   myDialog.findViewById(R.id.testwebview);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

            ImageButton close = (ImageButton)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
            close.setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener(){

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            myDialog.dismiss();
                    }                    
            });

            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what type of layout you're using with the WebView, but you may want to include both the WebView and a ProgressBar within a FrameLayout with the WebView initially hidden.  You can then show the WebView and hide the ProgressBar once the page completely loads.

R.layout.mydialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/testwebview"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:visibility="invisible"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/testprogressbar"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Within your Activity:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
public void onClick(View v) {

        myDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
        myDialog.setTitle("Test");
        myDialog.setCancelable(true);

        final WebView myWebView = (WebView)   myDialog.findViewById(R.id.testwebview);
        final ProgressBar myPB = (ProgressBar) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.testprogressbar);

        // Add WebViewClient to be notified of page load
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                // Show webview and hide progress bar
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myPB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        ImageButton close = (ImageButton)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
        close.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        myDialog.dismiss();
                }                    
        });

        myDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This was what I needed.  I really do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) like this

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.setMessage("Test");
progressDialog.show();
```